# Updating a wiki page with the REST API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How do you update a SharePoint 2013 wiki page using the REST API?

Three permutations:

- Reading an existing page (content only)
- Updating an existing page
- Creating a new page

For reading an existing page, of course I can just to a "GET" of the correct URL, but this also brings down all the various decorations around the actual data on the wiki page-- rather than fish that out myself, it would be better if there was a way to just get the content if that is possible.

Are there special endpoints is the REST API that allow for any of these three operations on wiki pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in GMasucci's post, there does not appear to be a clean or obvious way of instantiating pages through the REST API.

You can call the AddWikiPage method from the SOAP service at http://[site]/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx. This is an out of the box service that will be accessible unless it has been specifically locked down for whatever reason.

To read the content of a wiki page through the REST API, you can use the following endpoint:

https://[siteurl]/_vti_bin/client.svc/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/page/to/wikipage.aspx')/ListItemAllFields

The content is contained within the WikiContent field. You may want to add a select to that URL and return it as JSON to reduce the amount of data getting passed over if that is a concern.

As for updating the content of an existing wiki page, it is not something I have tried but I would imagine it's just like populating another field through the REST API. This is how I would expect to do it:

Do a HTTP POST to the same endpoint as above

---

Use the following HTTP headers:

- Cookie = "yourauthcookie"
- Content-Type = "application/json;odata=verbose"
- X-RequestDigest = "yourformdigest"
- X-HTTP-Method, "MERGE"
- If-Match = "etag value from entry node, returned from a GET to the above endpoint"

---

Post the following JSON body

```
{
 "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.SitePagesItem" },
 "WikiField" : "HTML entity coded wiki content goes here"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The interim answer I have found is to not utilise REST, as it appears to not be

- fully documented
- fully featured
- supported across Sharepoint 2013 and On-line in the same way

So my current recommendation would be to utilise the SOAP services to achieve the same, as these are more documented and easily accessible.